# How come I can use one variable in an object, but not another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to be able to use my iowa var in my object, but it doesn't seem to be working, yet the fillColor does seem to work. Any reason for this?

```
losingState = stateData.Abb;

        currentState = this;

        var iowa = 'IA';



      if(currentState.wins < 35){

        var fillColor = "red";

        $('#map').brett({

        stateSpecificStyles: {
         iowa : {fill: fillColor},
        },
```

Comment: the second `iowa` is a property key, so, it doesn't use the content of the variable named `iowa` ... in ES2015+ you can do `[iowa] : {fill: fillColor}`

Comment: If you put that down as an answer I will mark it as correct.